# Make C++ program receive file as parameter

Tags: c++, windows, file-association

What I want to do is a program like notepad. I want that all the ".txt" files, when I double click on them, open with my program instead of notepad. But I don't have any clue how to do this. So, in resume, I want:

Make my program predeterminate for .txt extension files
Make a program that open "automatically? " that file. Like when I open a test.txt file, and the notepad show the content of that file.

If you have any doubt, or I didn't explained very well, please ask!

Comment: Google is your friend: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/change-default-programs#1TC=windows-7

Comment: The title of your question is misleading, I thought you wanted to your program to accept a file as a parameter, which you would just have to do: `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {}`. And then manipulate argv to your will.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316204/how-to-set-an-application-as-the-default-program-of-opening-a-certain-type-of-fi

Comment: No answer is ok. I already know how to make my program the predeterminate for an file extension. What I want now is how to make the program itself. For example, a file that open a .txt file and show the content, in a way that when I open a text file, it opens with MY program (which will show the content of the file). Sorry, I don't speak english very well and it's hard to explain.

Comment: after you set your program as default for text file (manually or programmatically), when you open a .txt file it'll open your program instead of notepad. What else do you want?

Comment: I want to know how to do that program in C++, purely C++, no Visual C++. Something like this, but in C++:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714904/how-to-make-windows-autoview-a-file-with-my-program-and-how-to-make-the-program?rq=1

Comment: What do you mean by "purely C++"? Visual C++ is **not** a language. It's an IDE. Your question has already been answered in the other question. Just change the registry or call some APIs in your program

Comment: Well, no, it wasn't answered yet.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by changing your OS setting. For example: Right Click -> Open With -> Choose default program, then select a direction to your execute.

I don't think you can implement it into your program.

Comment: You can write your program to alter the registry and set the default program.

Comment: No answer is ok. I already know how to make my program the predeterminate for an file extension. What I want now is how to make the program itself. For example, a file that open a .txt file and show the content, in a way that when I open a text file, it opens with MY program (which will show the content of the file). Sorry, I don't speak english very well and it's hard to explain

Comment: @GastonFontenlaNuñez you want a file that opens your program with the text file? write a `.bat` file with content `your_program %1` that's all

Comment: I want a program that opens a file, by clicking the file itself, not the program! So, when I click my file to open it, it'll be open using my program. Oh god I'm so bad explaining things XD

Comment: Something like this. But in C++:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714904/how-to-make-windows-autoview-a-file-with-my-program-and-how-to-make-the-program?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you started:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12474/How-To-Make-A-Very-Simple-Text-Editor-Using-MFC-in

Comment: Something like that, but in C++ using console. Also, I don't need such things like the dialog for choosing a file, and for saving, etc. Just open and view the file.

Comment: Something like this but in C++:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714904/how-to-make-windows-autoview-a-file-with-my-program-and-how-to-make-the-program?rq=1